# JavaScript function only working on elements that have not already been manipulated by other functions

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to make a list of elements that has the functionality that if you click a list element its text turns red. I then wanted to make a button that would set all the elements in the list to black. However, the button only makes the list elements that have not been clicked, to black. The newly red items are unaffected.

```
<ul id="outerUl" style="color:pink">
    <li>First item in list</li>
    <li>Second item in list</li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" onclick="clearListColour()">
```

And the JavaScript:

```
<script>

var textColourChanger = function(e){
    e.target.style.color = 'red';
}

function clearListColour(){
    document.getElementById('outerUl').style.color = 'black';
}

document.getElementById('outerUl').addEventListener('click', textColourChanger);
```

When you hit the button, you can see in inspect that the color of the ul is set to black, but it doesn't seem to be able to make it in an li that has had it colour set by clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button you created sets 'color' attribute in `<ul>` element, so it will affect every element that is inside of `<ul>`

To overwrite the color from `<ul>` you need to set the color directly in `<li>` element

To achieve the effect of changing the color of only clicked `<li>` item, you would need to addEventListener to specific `<li>` items, so whenever one of them is clicked, its font color changes. To reset them all to black you'd have to do the same, change all of their font colors back to black, or manipulate css with !important flag on `<ul>` color.

Add ids to your `<li>` items like so `<li id="li1"> <li id="li2">`
addEventListeners to them by Id and you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you. I would like to understand this conceptually. When I load up the page, I have style="color:pink" which gets given to all the lis. Why does switching that to black via the DOM not have the same effect? Is there an associated concept in JS I could look up and learn about? Thank you Majkel

Answer (score 0):

more easy if you use some **css**:

```js
const 
  outerUl = document.getElementById('outerUl')
, BtClear = document.getElementById('bt-clearList')
  ;
  
outerUl.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li')) return
  
  e.target.classList.add('onRed')
  }
  
BtClear.onclick = e =>
  {
  outerUl.querySelectorAll('li.onRed').forEach(LI=>LI.classList.remove('onRed'))
  }
```

```css
#outerUl li {
  color  : pink;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
#outerUl li.onRed {
  color : red;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="outerUl">
  <li>First item in list</li>
  <li>Second item in list</li>
</ul>

<button id="bt-clearList"> Clear List Colours</button>
```

Comment: I thank you for this solution although it is a bit beyond my level so I will have to look some of the parts up.